# Zoom link from infowindow doesn't always render tiles

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the past I've put zoom in/out links in my infowindows but some recent api changes have broken this.

http://urloritdidnthappen.appspot.com/render/151001

Is there an event I can trigger from my zoom functions to get new tiles?

Comment: you may trigger resize on the map, but: which browser do you use, I don't have any problems with zooming from the links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gmap.panTo(point)` is redundant in your code, as the zoom in/out method handles this.  You can mitigate this by simply removing it from your `zoomIn` and `zoomOut` functions.

Revise your code as noted below:

```
function zoomIn(lat,lng) {
  point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng)
   zoom = gmap.getZoom()
   gmap.setZoom(zoom + 1)
}
function zoomOut(lat,lng) {
    point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng)
   zoom = gmap.getZoom()
   gmap.setZoom(zoom - 1)
}
```